# How to calculate +ve and -ve amounts on Totals in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below `Product table`, `Product ID` - 100 as duplicated twice, and also there are negative profits are needs to `Substract` while calculating the **Profit wise Total**.

```
PID | Pname | Profit
100     AB      20
100     AB      20
101     BC      30
102     CD     -10
103     DE     -10
```

Expected Result: 30

Please provide the `SQL query` to get this result. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(profit)
from (select distinct t.*
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE  AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID  ORDER BY PID ) AS rn,
    PID,Pname,Profit   FROM TableName

)

SELECT CAST(SUM(Profit) AS INT) AS Profit  FROM CTE  
WHERE rn=1
```

Note:- First you to get the DISTINCT Record then..use sum function...